# Design fitness function for polynomial approximation

Tags: r, optimization, stochastic-processes, genetic-algorithms

I'm trying to apply a `polynomial approximation` for a given function (via Genetic Algorithms), and so far  the results are not so good:

```
 # or any other GA package
  require(gaoptim)

  # for polyval
  require(pracma)

  # polynomial of degree 10
  ndeg = 10  
  ndim = ndeg + 1

  # search limits
  search.low = rep(-1, ndim)
  search.up = rep(1, ndim)

  # no. of data points
  m = 101 
  xi = seq(-1, 1, length = m)
  yi = 1 / (1 + (5*xi)^2)

  # fitness function
  pfn = function(p) max(abs(polyval(c(p), xi) - yi))

  # gaoptim perform maximization, so transform the fitness function
  pfninv = function(p){ 1/(pfn(p) + 1) }

  ## set up the ga
  ga = GAReal(pfninv, search.low, search.up, popSize = 500)
  ga$evolve(100)
  y2 = polyval(ga$bestIndividual(), xi)

  plot(xi, yi, ylim = range(c(yi, y2)), type = 'l', main = 'Runge function')
  lines(xi, y2, col = 'red')
```

[image]

Is there any strategy i can apply here, or this is a No-no approach? Maybe a better fitness function, or expand the search limits? Higher values of *popSize* doesn't seem to help too much.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Your target function is `yi = 1 /(1 + (5*xi)^2)`, which is not a polynomial, so it's going to be hard to approximate with a polynomial:

[image]

2) If you invert the target function, `yi = 1 + (5*xi)^2`, increase your bounds, e.g. `search.low = rep(-50, ndim)`; `search.up= rep(50, ndim)`

[image]

3) It's more common to take the [root-mean-square error (RMSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) as the fitness function instead of `max(abs(polyval(c(p), xi) - yi))`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i edited the question.

Comment: The issue is that the search space of your GA, viz. the polynomials of degree 10, is too far away from your target function `f(x) = 1 /(1 + (5*x)^2)`, hence the poor fitness value.

Comment: So theoretically, if i increase this search i should get better fits?

Comment: Yes but since your target function cannot be approximated by a polynomial, increasing the degree is useless. In evolutionary computation such task is called symbolic regression and we use genetic programming to optimize, not GA (GA typically requires to have a pretty good knowledge on the structure of your target function).